# Erro Array to String Conversion

Tags: php, android, json

Tenho uma aplicação Android que envia um Json em forma de string para o servidor em PHP. Testei com var_dump para verificar que os dados estavam sendo passados corretamente e está tudo ok. O problema é que, ao tentar acessar o json e atribuir valores de um array aninhado do objeto principal a um array em PHP, eu tenho um erro ao tentar incluir esse array no Mysql. 
Antes de fazer essa inclusão, testei somente PHP e MySQL e tudo está funcionando perfeitamente.

```
if  (!empty($_POST)){
   $info = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $json = json_decode($info, true);
   $login= "";
   $utilizaExercicio = array();
  //var_dump($info);

   foreach($json['Paciente'][0] as $nome){
      $login = $nome;
   }


   foreach ($json['Paciente'][1]as $exercicio){
       $utilizaExercicio[] = array($exercicio);
   }

for ($i=0; sizeOf($utilizaExercicio) > $i; $i++){

    $exercicios = mysqli_fetch_array($ordernar);
    $sql1 = ("UPDATE exercicio_paciente
             INNER JOIN pacientes ON (exercicio_paciente.idpaciente =  pacientes.ID)
             INNER JOIN exercicios ON (exercicios.idexercicios = exercicio_paciente.idexercicio)
             SET exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio=$utilizaExercicio[$i]     
             WHERE exercicio_paciente.idexercicio= {$exercicios['idexercicio']} AND
                   pacientes.ID=(SELECT c.ID FROM (SELECT * FROM pacientes) as c 
                                 WHERE c.login_paciente = '$login');");

    $salvo = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);

    if ($salvo)
        $sucesso = 1;
    else
        $sucessoLocal=0;

}
}
```

Aqui, o erro acontece em SET `exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio=$utilizaExercicio[$i]`

E meu json:

```
{Paciente:[{"Nome":"Rafael"},
           {Exercicios:[{"0":"1"},
                        {"1":"0"},
                        {"2":"0"}]}]
}
```

O que estaria errado?
OBS: A estrutura do JSON eu montei aqui, pois não consegui passar para um arquivo específico, mas acredito que ela esteja correta.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode concatenar um `array` (array de exercícios) com uma `string`. Quando você precisar transformar `array` em `string` para salvar no banco de dados, você pode utilizar um dos três métodos abaixo.

#### Utilizando [**json_encode**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)

Você utilizar o seguinte código `json_encode($utilizaExercicio[$i]);`

```
exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio=\"".json_encode($utilizaExercicio[$i])."\"
```

Com essa função você terá uma `query` semelhante a esta:

```
SET exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio="[[["1"],{"1":"0"},{"2":"0"}]]"
```

---

#### Utilizando [**serialize**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

Você utilizar o seguinte código `serialize($utilizaExercicio[$i]);`

```
exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio=\"".serialize($utilizaExercicio[$i])."\"
```

Com essa função você terá uma `query` semelhante a esta:

```
SET exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio="a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}i:1;a:1:{i:1;s:1:"0";}i:2;a:1:{i:2;s:1:"0";}}}"
```

---

#### Utilizando [**print_r**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php):

Você utilizar o seguinte código `print_r($utilizaExercicio[$i], true)`

```
exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio=\"".print_r($utilizaExercicio[$i], true)."\"
```

Com essa função você terá uma `query` semelhante a esta:

```
SET exercicio_paciente.utilizar_exercicio="Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 0
                )

        )

)"
;
```

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas ainda precisaria manipular essas entradas? Eu coloquei as 3 e em todas apareceu o seguinte erro: "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array".<br/>
\"".print_r($utilizaExercicio[$i], true)."\" As abas estariam posicionadas corretamente para só substituir pelo $utilizaExercicio[$i]?